# Looking for the right terminology: Subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with non-zero measure everywhere

Tags: terminology

I'd like to know if there exists an established name for a set $T \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ with the following property:

For every $x \in T$ there exists a convex set $C \subset T$ such that $x \in C$ and $\lambda(C) > 0$
where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Intuitively, what I am trying to describe is a set that "has volume everywhere", such that a point $x \in T$ can be moved a small distance in any of $n$ independent directions and still remain inside $T$.

Comment: Isn't that condition equivalent to being everywhere dense?

Comment: nevermind, not quite.

Comment: If you replace "convex" with "open", then I think your statement is basically the same as requiring that the measure space induced on $T$ has support the whole of $T$. A supported point in a measure space is a point in which every open neighbourhood of that point has positive measure; the _support_ of a measure is all the supported points.